# Matlab *.mat files associated with MS Office

Tags: windows-7, file-association, matlab

When MATLAB creates a binary file with extension .mat on my Windows 7 (64 bit) computer, Windows declares it in a directory as a "Microsoft Office Access Table Shortcut". Windows also does not provide the option to "Open With" any other program in the right-click menu.  The file works properly if it is dragged and dropped into MATLAB. How can I change the file association to properly open the file with MATLAB?

Answer (score 7):

Start->Default Programs->Associate a file type or protocol with a program.

Answer (score 4):

Right click an example file.

Choose 'Open With' on the menu then 'Choose Program'.

In the new window, choose MatLab & click the "Always use the selected program to open this kind of file" and click 'Open'.

The program *should* now be associated..

Comment: For this particular problem, windows does not provide the "Open With" option.  I don't know if that's because it thinks that the .mat file is a shortcut or what, but it doesn't provide that option.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 7, go to control panel, Default Programs, Associate a file type with a specific program

This should give you a list of file extensions and their associated applications. Select the .mat extension, then click change program (button at upper right) and browse to select the 'matlab' executable.

[Here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/how-to-set-file-associations-in-windows-7-not-open/e3470b2d-385c-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5?auth=1)'s the MS ref

Answer (score 1):

**With Windows 10 it is currently (29.04.2020) not possible to set in system-control so:**

**If you have access to registry-editor**

1. export key:

   Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.m
2. export key (backup):

   Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.mat
3. delete key:

   Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.mat
4. open the export of "Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.m" with your favorite text-editor and change ".m" to ".mat"
5. now double-click on the edited export of "Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.m"

==================================================

What a mess Microsoft, shame on you for that.

Answer (score 0):

There's an official utility function from MathWorks that is included in MATLAB itself that will fix this issue. See this [MathWorks technical support solution](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-VW0R7/index.html?solution=1-VW0R7) for details.

Comment: That's no utility function, it's a checklist for using Windows Explorer to change the file association.

Comment: @BenVoigt Looks like they've changed the content of that page since I linked to it. The utility function always used to just do basically the same things that other answers have suggested, in any case.